# multiple deletion by using check box in angular 2

Tags: html, angular

**this is the code in html page, need code for both component and service please help for this problem  ** *multiple deletion by using check box in angular 2* **i posted only html code but i dont know code for both components and service here the code have using single deletions but i need multiple deletions**

```
    <div class="card-content table-responsive" *ngIf="this.pagedItems!=null && this.pagedItems.length > 0">

    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="text-danger" style="font-weight: bold">Sl NO</th>
              <!--  <th class="text-danger" style="font-weight: bold">Date</th>-->
                <th class="text-danger" style="font-weight: bold">Income/Expense</th>
                <th class="text-danger" style="font-weight: bold">Payment Mode</th>
                <th class="text-danger" style="font-weight: bold">Debtor</th>
                <th class="text-danger" style="font-weight: bold">Remarks</th>
                <th class="text-danger" style="font-weight: bold">Amount</th>
                <th class="text-danger" style="font-weight: bold"></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr  *ngFor="let item of this.pagedItems | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 500, currentPage: p }; let i = index"  >
                    <td>{{i+1}}</td>
                <!--    <td>{{item.date_of_entry}}</td>-->

                    <td>{{item.income_expense}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.payment_mode}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.creditor_fname}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.remarks}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.amount}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.entry_id}}</td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="deletecheck"></td>
           <td class="td-actions text-right">
                   <button type="button" rel="tooltip" title="Edit" class="btn btn-primary btn-simple btn-xs" (click) = "editSales({entryid:item.entry_id,InExp:item.income_expense,Amt:item.amount,Paymode:item.payment_mode,Debtr:item.creditor_id,Vehic:item.vechicle_no,Remarks:item.remarks})">
                        <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
                    </button>
                </td>   
            </tr>

        <button (click)="deleteSelected()">Delete</button>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <br>
    <pagination-controls (pageChange)="p = $event"></pagination-controls>

</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand the question, you can just click `delete` button  multiple times. Also, why are you sending new JS object on `edit`, when you can do this `edit(item)`?

Comment: <td><input type="checkbox" name="deletecheck"></td>  <button (click)="deleteSelected()">Delete</button> consider these codes.Ignore edit and close button ..when we check multiple checkboxes , selected rows only get deleted from the particular list. please help me

Answer (score 0):

Add an array of selected items in the component:

`selectedItems: Item[];`

Add another button to (de)select items:

```
                <button type="button" rel="tooltip" title="Select" class="btn btn-info btn-simple btn-xs" (click) = "selectSales({entryid:item.entry_id})">
                    <i class="material-icons">close</i>
                </button>
```

In component:

```
selectSales(item) {
    const indexFound = this.selectedItems.indexOf(selected => selected.id === item.id;
    if (indexFound > -1) {
        this.selectedItems.splice(indexFound, 1);
    } else {
        this.selectedItems.push(item);
    }
}

deleteSelected() {
    this.selectedItems.forEach(item => {
        // delete each item
    });
}
```